# Jetpack Compose - bind to an array of objects does not update UI

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-databinding

I am working on a project for writing an App with a chat messanger.
I am using Firestore to store the messages. After loading the messages inside the app I am attaching `snapshotListener` which enable my App to be notified automatically whenever a new message is created or another one altered.

For the local representation of given messages I am using a `DataHandler` *singleton* with an `ArrayList` storing each message. Therefore, when the `snapshotListener` is triggered, the `DataHandler` adds the new message to its list.

Now I want the UI to show a Text for every message inside given ArrayList and update with every change:

```kotlin
var messages by remember { mutableStateOf(dataHandler.messageList) }

Column {
    messages.forEach { msg ->
        Text(text = msg.text)
    }
}
```

But when I add a new message via the firestore console, I can see that the new message is added to the `DataHandler` but not displayed on the screen.

Is there a way to bind to the `ArrayList` instance without needing to pass update functions through activities and fragments?

Comment: Did you try using SnapshotStateList or making messageList a mutableStateOf<List<>> https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#mutableStateListOf()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!!
@pushpull mentioned `SnapshotStateList<ChatMessage>` as Type for the `messageList` inside the `dataHandler` and initializing it using `mutableStateListOf<ChatMessage>()`

Also, the composable function is way more simple utilizing the singleton:

```
val dataHandler = DataHanndler.getInstance()
Column {
    dataHandler.messageList.forEach { msg ->
        Text(text = msg.text)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using this construct of `remember`, your `messages` value will only be updated if you initiate it yourself, like this:

```
messages = listOf()
```

if you don't need to modify the list of `messages` yourself (based on your description, you really don't need to) and just want to keep track of actual `messages`, then you can use something like this:

```
val messages by dataHandler.messageList.collectAsState()
```

and your `dataHandler` must be `MutableStateFlow`